# Facebook LIKE count after domain page url change

Tags: php, facebook

I have used facebook like button in my page, but now my page url is change,
Then how to get the previous count.
example, previously my url was http://x.domain.com now that page is redirecting to http://domain.com/x/ . now showing liked count 0,how to get the previous liked count?
Can anybody help?

Comment: I think it's not possible to "migrate" the like counts...

Answer (score 0):

I got it,
its possible, if the url is permanently redirected with 301, then facebook and google both will take care with canonical url.
they made  http://x.domain.com is url and http://domain.com/x/ is a canonical url.
count will come autometic.